# Cannot remove architecture i386

Tags: apt, kali-linux, x86, architecture

I'm using 64 bit Kali Linux, previously installed i386 architecture and now I want to remove it, because it downloads about 30Mb data for 32bit package every time `apt update`.

I tried `dpkg --remove-architecture i386`, it failed with

*dpkg: error: cannot remove architecture 'i386' currently in use by the database*

Google says the i386 packages should be removed first, but some package like "gcc-12-base:i386, libc6:i386, libcrypt1:i386, libgcc-s1:i386" cannot be removed, how to solve it?

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to remove them simultaneously, and force their removal in spite of their “protected” status:

```
dpkg --purge --force-remove-protected {gcc-12-base,libc6,libcrypt1,libgcc-s1}:i386
```